# Coloring an object

Tags: modeling, materials

[image]

I am currently modelling the head part of the above character, and stuck with coloring.

The head consists of two colors - grey and white.
The border between the two colors are curved and below is what my sphere looks like.

[image]

I'm really bad at Blender and right now all I can think of doing so is just adding edges onto the mesh by connecting vertices,

and I did so on the 2nd image, and I cant get that curve like the first image.

**My question is how can I get that smooth curve on an object to color differently?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your character is a very simple cartoony model. Is there a reason why you want to model the geometry?

You can get away with one material and simple texturing. It's the perfect job for the **Texture Stencil** brush.

This is just the normal brush with a loaded texture image, and *Tool Setting > Texture > Mapping* set to `Stencil`. Set the brush color to pure white. Then you can paint your image on the model.

Use right-click (<kbd>RMB</kbd>) to move the stencil image, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> to scale, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> to rotate.

[image: textured head]

If you really want to add the geometry you can use the *Knife* tool (<kbd>K</kbd>) to add the edge loops after you textured the head.